# AGP 7.0.0 configuration cache support in Artifactory plugin

Tags: artifactory

I’m upgrading my Android gradle files to AGP 7.0.x. One of the nice features is configuration cache. When I enable it I get few thousands errors in Jfrog artifactory plugin. Is there any suitable version of this plugin to use that supports new feature?

Comment: Please open a feature request and specify what do you see in the logs here: https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thanks @yahavi, here it is: https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/601

Comment: @yahavi It'd be a great update to the Artifactory Gradle plugin indeed! Every second we can scrape from our builds counts :D